# how to achieve transaction info of all the blocks

Tags: transactions, blockchain, historical-trade-data

I use https://chain.api.btc.com/v3/block/date/20151215 to achieve list of blocks and also use https://chain.api.btc.com/v3/tx/0eab89a271380b09987bcee5258fca91f28df4dadcedf892658b9bc261050d96?verbose=3 to get transaction info for a single transaction. Now I have a question. To access transaction info of all blocks what should I do?
when I copy the hash of any block from the list of the first link in the second link, it shows error.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're pasting a ***block hash*** into a field that expects a ***transaction hash***.

It looks like `btc.com` doesn't support listing all transactions for a given block, it will only give a tx count: https://btc.com/api-doc#Block.

Blockchain.info does, however at the api endpoint:

`https://blockchain.info/rawblock/$block_hash`

So, you can copy the hash of any block from the list of the first link in your answer to the `$block_hash` field in `https://blockchain.info/rawblock/$block_hash`.